# Windows 10 pro unable to remove Bose QuitComfort 35

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have been trying for the last half hour to find ways to remove my Bose QuitComfort 35 from the bluetooth list of devices.

Here is what I see in the "Bluetooth & other devices" windows

[image]

The device is not turned off I just can't pair it now. Not sure exactly what happened, I have been using the device without issues but after I turned off the device I was unable to pair it again and now I am unable to remove it.

I have tried removing in the device manager as well. I can get rid of the Bose QuitComfort 35 under "Other devices" but not the one in Audio.

I am the administrator in my account. Is there anything else I need to do???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may be a shot in the dark, but it appears this may be due to Bluetooth driver issues. Please try the following:

1. Completely disconnect your computer from the internet.
2. Open your **Device Manage**r as Administrator.
3. Under **Bluetooth**, remove each of the Enumerators (not the driver).
4. Under **Human Interface Devices**, remove any Bluetooth devices.
5. Restart your computer.
6. Connect the computer to the internet.
7. Pair devices.

Found here: https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/win10-not-removing-bluetooth-device.2099/#post-22640

Comment: Will only be able to try this over the weekend. Thanks for this! I will report back once I have tried it.

Comment: Thanks! I spent countless hours on this problem. I wish I found this earlier.